# rails custom validation on form and backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation, custom-validators

I have a form for which i need a special validation. There is a field called fund_name and a field called company_name (from tables funds and companies respectively, where a company can have many funds). Company information and Fund information are taken from the user on a single form (with nested attributes)

Requirement is, that a name of the company (or a fund) should be unique across company names AND fund names. I created a custom validator and a remote validator for [client side validations plugin](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations).

Problem is, it wouldn't validate the CURRENT company and fund for uniqueness. I could override the fields with blur, while calling isValid on the field first, but i wanted the above mentioned plugin to cater for it.

Suggestions on how to best do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
validates :fund_name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :company_name }
```

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness).

Comment: This would only be useful if fund_name and company_name are in the same model. Fund Name is stored as :name in funds table, and Company Name is stored as :name in companies table.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : write in your model

```
validates :name,presence: true, :uniqueness => {
                          :case_sensitive => false,
                          scope: :company_name
                        }
```

Comment: Sorry but checks only the uniqueness from the database. Not on the form as it is filled out.